# How to define constant structure

Tags: c

Can any one give me some ideas about constant structure? 
Please post some example.
In my structure I define only members constant, not a variable, then that is a constant structure?
Or in another structure both variable and member constant so that is constant structure?

what is the difference between these two structure exactly which one structure is constant?

`struct student{
              const int rolll
}stu;`

`struct student{
              const int rolll
}const stu;`

Comment: You should post some example of the code you're thinking about.  It's hard to know whether you're on the right track or not when you don't show your code.

Comment: Please edit your code into your question — do _not_ try to treat it as a comment.

Comment: Simply prepend `const` to your object  definition: `const struct my_struct my_const_object = { initial member values here};`.  Are you looking for something more than that?

Comment: What is for you the difference between a "variable" and a "member" in a structure?

Answer (score 2):

There is no formal definition of a constant structure in C. We can consider a structure object declared with `const` to be a constant structure. For example, if we have:

```
struct X { int q; };

const struct X foo = { 3 };
```

Then we can consider `foo` to be a constant structure. We could further build `const` into a alias for the type using `typedef:

```
typedef const struct X { int q; } ConstantX;

ConstantX foo = { 3 };
```

Then it is reasonable to consider `ConstantX` to be a constant structure type.

Note that declaring the members to be `const` does not define a constant structure. If we have:

```
struct X { const int q; };

struct X foo = { 3 }, bar = { 4 };
```

Then we cannot modify the member `q` directly; a C compiler will issue a diagnostic for:

```
foo.q = 5;
```

However, the structure itself is not constant, and we may change it; a C compiler will accept:

```
foo = bar;
```